# How do I prevent update on wrong data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario, like I want insert a record into a table, then I
   update same record by getting the last inserted row Id, so now my
   issue is if a another user inserts a new record before the first
   record gets updated, so according to my scenario I get the last
   inserted row Id , in this case update applied on the last row instead
   of the first one, any solution please.

Comment: why last inserted row Id why not specific row id (primary key)? do you need to target last row specifically?

Comment: Instead of Insert then Update, can't you simply include the updated data in your initial Insert?

Comment: No, based on my need I have to update it after the insertion

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag *only* with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for **SQL Server**
if you have an Identity column in the Table, after inserting use the `@@IDENTITY` variable or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to get the Identity value of the Row inserted and then while updating use the Identity Filed in the Where Clause.

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(FullName)
VALUES('My Name')

SELECT @IdVal = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE MyTable SET Phone='1234' WHERE IdCol = @IdVal
```

Comment: @jawed . . . Unfortunately, if you *are* using SQL Server, then the best way to do this uses the `OUTPUT` clause.  This answer should not be upvoted.  I'm not providing an answer, because the question had incompatible database tags.